# table of contents font changes to bold when it is declared as regular

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, xetex, fontspec, polyglossia

I am trying to create a table of contents and I use Devanagari font. I declare the font to be Shobhika Regular, but in the table of contents environment it changes to boldface. How to prevent this from happening. My code is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{footnpag}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[larger]{skt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\newcommand{\san}[1][1.35]{
    \catcode`\^=12
    \catcode`\~=12
    \fontspec[WordSpace=0.75,Script=Devanagari,Mapping=sk-dvn,Scale=#1]{Shobhika Regular}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\label{ds_contents}
\centerline{\san vi.sayasuucii}

\contentsline{chapter}%
{\numberline{\bf 1}{\hspace{3mm}%
{\san namaste}}%
\hspace{3mm}\dotfill ~~~}%
{\pageref{namaste}}

{\san namaste}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can, the namaste in the table of contents environment is bold when the same thing outside is has the correct font.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing here is that `\contentsline{chapter}` calls a macro called `\l@chapter` which sets the chapter-style entries for the Table of Contents. This macro also includes some formatting and, by default, uses **bold** for the chapter titles. You can use [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) to adjust the formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
  \bfseries Contents
\end{center}

\contentsline{chapter}%
  {\numberline{1}Greetings}%
  {1}

Greetings

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the spacing of the leader dots by adjusting `\cftdotsep`. For example, if you want the dots to be closer together, use `\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{3}` (default is `4.5`).

Comment: I get the right font. But my dotfill is reduced in length.

Comment: The font problem is solved but my dotfill is reduced in length. It fills up only half the line.

Comment: @Sundar: I've added a reference to your leader/dot fill in my answer. Best to use [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) to specify all the elements of your "ToC," rather than entering some of the elements manually.